# Error occured when installing zensols.dltools

Tags: python, package, pycharm, anaconda

I'm trying to install this package(zensols.dltool) using Anaconda,but it seems like some configuration file or package is missing.

Error messeage:

```
(base) C:\Users\MXY>pip3 install zensols.dltools -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/
Collecting zensols.dltools
  Downloading https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/e1/b4/e9c1773214900c344464ecddaf28648354a51ac24f9176ee77853b06667d/zensols.dltools-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting scipy==1.3.1 (from zensols.dltools)
  Downloading https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/ee/5b/5afcd1c46f97b3c2ac3489dbc95d6ca28eacf8e3634e51f495da68d97f0f/scipy-1.3.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 23.6/23.6 MB 403.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [188 lines of output]
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['E:\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_lapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['E:\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Anaconda3\\libs']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_clapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['E:\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Anaconda3\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      lapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack not found in ['E:\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

        NOT AVAILABLE

      <string>:386: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --output-dir C:\Users\MXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-vboaborn --keep-egg-info'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      Running from scipy source directory.
      C:\Users\MXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-huz19z_r\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
          Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
          the ATLAS environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      C:\Users\MXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-huz19z_r\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      C:\Users\MXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-huz19z_r\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\MXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-huz19z_r\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 366, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\MXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-huz19z_r\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\MXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-huz19z_r\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 505, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 501, in setup_package
        File "C:\Users\MXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-huz19z_r\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
          config = configuration()
        File "<string>", line 403, in configuration
      numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

What is "numpy.distutils"? I tried to install it but failed.

My virtual environments are in Disk E, and my user config file is in Disk C, does this has an impact? But I don't know how to change.

Comment: Issue looks like this; your main package depends on scipy 1.3.1. At least on pypi.org the latest release of scipy only provides binary packageas for python 3.7. Because scipy contains code that needs to be compiled for it to work, setup process tries to look for working compilers which you dont have installed and fails.

Comment: Easiest way would probably be use python 3.7 for this scenario if you are not able to handle the installation of all the dependencies to setup working compiler toolchain.